# Is there a reliable way to get __name__ in Manim when using multiprocessing

Tags: python-multiprocessing, manim

I am working on a video that has a simulation of ideal gas (points) or realistic gas (circles) going on in the background for parts of it. In order to make processing go faster with a useful number of "molecules" for the realistic gas, I've been using the multiprocessing python package. This requires checks for `"__name__ = '__main__'"` in regular python to avoid bad multiprocessing conditions. In manim 0.16 versions, I was able to use `"__name__ = 'py'"`, but this broke in the upgrade to 0.17 versions. I eventually fixed it by doing a quick check for whatever `__name__` is now by having the main process `print("__name__ is now ", __name__)`, which now outputs `"path.to.working.dir.main"`.

Is there an easy way to find out what to use from within the program without having to check and fix with every update?

In manim 0.16 versions, checking for

`__name__ = "py"`

was good enough. This changed in manim 0.17 versions and it took me a while to figure out why my animation was crashing. I finally resolved it by inserting a

`print("__name__ is now ", __name__)`

near the top of the code to find out what to use now. However, this seems like an ineffective approach in the long run (will I have to go through this in version 0.18?) and I'd like to find a better way, more reliable, more automated way.

Comment: Why not write your animation in form of a pure Python file as described here https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/contributing/performance.html#running-an-animation-as-a-script and use the normal `if __name__ == "__main__": ...`?

Comment: Could you explain why you need to know the exact value of `__name__`?  The `if __name__ == "__main__"` requirement is for a highly specific reason, and as far as I know it doesn't matter what the module's real name is otherwise, as long as it != "`__main__`".